# Display only when it should - else hide

Tags: php

Can someone tell me how I can get this code to not show the app download button on a device that is not listed below?

I know it can be done but I'm not really sure.

Thanks.

```
<?php
$ua=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
switch(true) {
  case stripos($ua,'android') :
    $device = 'android'; break;
  case stripos($ua,'ipad') :
    $device = 'ipad'; break;
  case stripos($ua,'iphone') :
    $device = 'iphone'; break;
}
?> 
<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button android"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=<?php echo $device; ?>' " type="submit" /></li></ul>
```

Comment: I dunno. Maybe change it to mobile.

Comment: it is  android question or ios question ??

Comment: Dude... don't use any random tags, people gets confused bcoz of that.

Comment: Well as it mentions android how is it random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `default` case. If not matches, default case will work.

```
<?php
$ua=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
switch(true) {
  case stripos($ua,'android') :
    $device = 'android'; break;
  case stripos($ua,'ipad') :
    $device = 'ipad'; break;
  case stripos($ua,'iphone') :
    $device = 'iphone'; break;
  default:
    $device = false;
}
?> 

<?php if($device): ?>
<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button android"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=<?php echo $device; ?>' " type="submit" /></li></ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
<?php
$ua=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
switch(true) {
  case stripos($ua,'android') :
    $device = 'android'; break;
  case stripos($ua,'ipad') :
    $device = 'ipad'; break;
  case stripos($ua,'iphone') :
    $device = 'iphone'; break;
  default:
   $device = 'unknown';
}

if($device != 'unknown')
{
?> 
<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button android"><input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location='apps.php?id=<?php echo $device; ?>' " type="submit" /></li></ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Not tested, my PHP is rusty, so unsure if I did the default case right..

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $device='';
    $ua=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    switch(true) {
      case stripos($ua,'android') :
        $device = 'android'; break;
      case stripos($ua,'ipad') :
        $device = 'ipad'; break;
      case stripos($ua,'iphone') :
        $device = 'iphone'; break;
    }
    if($device != '')
    {
        echo '<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button android">
            <input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location=\'apps.php?id='.$device.'\'" type="submit" />
            </li></ul>';
    }
?>
```

**Alternatively** try the `simple one` using `preg_match`

```
<?php
    $ua=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (preg_match('/android|ipad|iphone/i', $ua)) {
        echo '<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button android">
            <input name="Submit" value="App Downloads" onclick="window.location=\'apps.php?id='.$device.'\'" type="submit" />
            </li></ul>';
    }
?>
```